# Hadoop chaining job error expected org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm learning hadoop and I am trying to reproduce a job chain example.
This one sums the sales per video games.
Then the 2nd mapper is there only to swap key and value so it gets ordered by sales amount and not the title

I am getting this error on the second mapper:
Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

I am confused on where is the LongWritable is coming from since its only Text and DoubleWritable everywhere, what am I missing?

//1st mapper

```
public class MonMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable>{

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    String line = value.toString();
    // regex to avoid split on a comma between double quotes
    String [] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
    String jeux = tokens[1];
    Double sales = Double.parseDouble(tokens[10]);
    
    context.write(new Text(jeux), new DoubleWritable(sales));
}
```

}

// reducer

```
public class MonReduce extends Reducer<Text,DoubleWritable,Text,DoubleWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Double somme = 0.0 ;
    for (DoubleWritable val : values){
        somme += val.get();
    }
    
    context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(somme));
}
```

}

//2nd mapper

```
public class KeyValueSwapper extends Mapper<Text, DoubleWritable, DoubleWritable, Text>{

public void map(Text key, DoubleWritable value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    context.write(value, key);
}
```

}

//main

```
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MonMap.class);       
    job.setCombinerClass(MonReduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MonReduce.class);
    
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
    if (!job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
        System.exit(1);
      }
    
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf, "sort by sales");
    job2.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(KeyValueSwapper.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWritable.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[2]));
    
    if (!job2.waitForCompletion(true)) {
      System.exit(1);
    }
    
   }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your mappers are both using FileInputFormat, which requires reading `<LongWritable, Text` inputs

That being said, you'll need to read, split and parse the lines of text in the second mapper

Overall I'd recommend using Pig, Hive, Spark, or Flink... Or just Pandas if you don't need Hadoop. Not many people use plain mapreduce in my experience